# Quiver or Barb with a date axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

What is the standard way of plotting a timeseries (dates) of quiver or barbs? I often have timeseries in a Pandas DataFrame and plot them like this:

```
plt.plot(df.index.to_pydatetime(), df.parameter)
```

This works very well, the x-axis can be treated as genuine dates which is very convenient for formatting or setting the xlim() with Datetime object etc.

Using this with quiver or barbs in the same way result in:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

This can be overcome with something like:

```
ax.barbs(df.index.values.astype('d'), np.ones(size) * 6.5, df.U.values, df.V.values, length=8, pivot='middle')
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.to_pydatetime())
```

Which works, but would mean that everywhere i have to convert the dates to floats and then manually override the labels. Is there a better way?

Here is some sample code resembling my case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

size = 10

wspd = np.random.randint(0,40,size=size)
wdir = np.linspace(0,360 * np.pi/180, num=size)
U = -wspd*np.sin(wdir)
V = -wspd*np.cos(wdir)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([U,V]).T, index=pd.date_range('2012-1-1', periods=size, freq='M'), columns=['U', 'V'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(15,4))

ax.plot(df.index.values.astype('d'), df.V * 0.1 + 4, color='k')
ax.quiver(df.index.values.astype('d'), np.ones(size) * 3.5, df.U.values, df.V.values, pivot='mid')
ax.barbs(df.index.values.astype('d'), np.ones(size) * 6.5, df.U.values, df.V.values, length=8, pivot='middle')

ax.set_xticklabels(df.index.to_pydatetime())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest converting your dates to timestamps, and then using a custom formatter ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter)) to convert the seconds to date format of your choice.  You will probably have to play with the locator ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html)) a bit to get it to look good (in terms of spacing/labels fitting).

```
import datetime
def tmp_f(dt,x=None):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(dt).isoformat()
mf = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(tmp_f)

ax = gca()
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mf)
draw()
```

Comment: What do you mean by timestamps? If i use your code with `mpl.dates.date2num(df.index)` i end up with dates in 09-Jan-1970. But you put me on the right track, see my solution below.

Comment: @RutgerKassies by timestamps I mean unix time (uint seconds from jan 1 1970), which is not what`date2num` does (it gives days from 1-1-1).

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the following code:

```
idx = mpl.dates.date2num(df.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))

ax.plot(idx, df.V * 0.1 + 4, 'o-',color='k')
ax.quiver(idx, np.ones(size) * 3.5, df.U.values, df.V.values, pivot='mid')
ax.barbs(idx, np.ones(size) * 6.5, df.U.values, df.V.values, length=8, pivot='middle')
```