# matplotlib quiver with datetime?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot a figure with the x scale was date.
While plot `contourf` it complete worked, but while `quiver` it's wrong.

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import datetime

dates = np.arange('2010-01-01', '2016-01-01', type='datetime64[D]').astype(object)
y = np.arange(10)
u = np.random.rand(y.size * len(times)).reshape(len(times), y.size)
v = np.random.rand(y.size * len(times)).reshape(len(times), y.size)

# now plot contourf, it worked.
plt.contourf(dates, y, u.T)
# plot quiver , error!!!
plt.quiver(dates, y, u.T, v.T)
```

[image]

Error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'datetime.date' and 'int'

Comment: i find a way to solve it.
from matplotlib.date import date2num, first convert date to num, and then plot quiver, last format the xdate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quiver or Barb with a date axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950053/quiver-or-barb-with-a-date-axis)